# Foundation 6 with Rails Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, simple-form, zurb-foundation-6

[Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) includes a Foundation 5 template.

However, I cannot find any template files modified for Foundation 6 on the web.

How well does the generated forms work with Foundation 6? Moreover, any generous share of Foundation 6 template or tips on modifying the existing template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if simple_form can be configured to provide what Foundation 6 requires for fields with errors.

Until I can figure that out (if, if, if), I have this hack in place using Sass `@extend`:

```
// TODO: This is a hack to get Foundation 6 styles on simple_form 
// elements with errors.
.input.error {
  label {
    @extend .is-invalid-label;
  }

  input,
  textarea,
  select {
    @extend .is-invalid-input;
  }

  small.error {
    @extend .form-error;
    @extend .is-visible;
  }
}
```

Are you dissatisfied with this answer? I am too. I hope that someone can "show me up" on this with a better answer.

Comment: Thank you Chris for being helpful :)

Comment: @Gavin You're welcome. We can share our torment together of having wonderful `TODO`s in our apps like this one. :D

Comment: @ChrisPeters so when you install simple_form, can you use the foundation 5 generator then this hack ?

Comment: @Pak That's what I did. Can't remember if I modified anything else in the generated config.

Comment: @ChrisPeters is right. But I have to rename `application.css` to `application.scss` (SCSS), and add `@import 'foundation_and_overrides';` before that snippet

Answer (score 1):

Just a little progress, you can set in config file `simple_form.rb` this:

```
config.wrappers .... do |c|
  ...  
  c.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :small, class: 'form-error is-visible'
  ..
end
```

and error messages will be formatted .. However, I did not find solution for labels and inputs, so the @Chris's solution for labels and inputs is still needed. However, if you don't need red labels and inputs, this is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

To get hints (aka help text) working correctly, edit config/simple_form_foundation.rb and add:

```
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: 'help-text' }
```